# Runtime function declaration on event handler with variables is executing the handlers function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function which adds some rows to a table and at the end there is an expander.
When the page is first rendered, there are 30 rows and the expanders are triggered by mouse clicks as the `onclick();` events are described inline in the document markup.

When I add the new `onclick();` I am doing so like this in a loop to load the next 30 objects via some JSON I get through XHR.

```
newCell.onclick = (function(id){toggleCertificate(id, this, i);})(currCert['id']);
```

now `currCert` contains an integer `'id'` I want to be in this handler so that for each `i`, there will be a different integer in place of `currCert['id']` which is what `toggleCertificate(integer id ...);` expects

```
newCell.onclick = function(){toggleCertificate(12983, this, 5);};
```

`this` needs to be passed down as if it refers to the `newCell` object and the other two variables need to become passed down as integers to be interpreted when `toggleCertificate` is executed as their values

What am I doing wrong? I find this syntax quite tricky surrounding attaching functions to event handlers.

Currently this code behaves as trying to execute "toggleCertificate" with data I cannot debug.
Firebug's DOM inspecter reveals the attached onclick becomes

```
(function (){toggleCertificate(currCert['id']), this, i})
```

And the page begins executing all the correct `onclick` functions without being clicked and simultaneously.

I want the onclick event to equal this string

```
"toggleCertificate(" + currCert['id'] + ", this, " + i + ");"
```

Sorry if any words I have used not proper JavaScript standards especially concerning "event handlers", "object" and "inline" -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the immediate function to return a function:

```
newCell.onclick = (function(id, i) {
   return function() {
     toggleCertificate(id, this, i);
   }
})(currCert['id'], i);
```

onClick requires a function that can be executed later (when there is a click) and so that is what the output of the immediate function must be. The reason for using an immediate function at all is because the function attached to onClick is being generated programatically based on the values of i and currCert['id']

Comment: The attached event came out like this now `(function (id){toggleCertificate(id, that, j);})` and needs to be like `function onclick(event) {toggleCertificate(6859, this, 29);}`

Comment: Okay I was finally able to get my desired functionality out with this which I feel was only due to miscommunication on my part `newCell.onclick = (function(id, i){return function(){toggleCertificate(id, this, i);};})(currCert['id'], i);`

Do you know why the behaviour is such that you are required to return a function in a function to use external variables in it? Is it just the only way to have variables in local scope passed literally and not as pointers to the inline function?

Comment: You're basically right. The outer function creates its own scope (a closure) which stores the values of id and i. This is needed as both id and i are changing as you iterate through the loop